# Laravel eloquent call optional relationship in query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get a query with Laravel eloquent. I have a table `posts` which has a morph relationship column `author`. This `author` column can refer to a `users` table or `admins` table. So this is the way I am getting the `author` of each `posts`:

```php
    $query = Post::with(['author']);
```

Now, there's another table I want to include if the `author` is a `user`, which is `address`. The problem is, there's no `address` relationship in `admin` table.
So, when I try to do this,

```php
    $query = Post::with([
        'author' => function ($q) {
            $q->with('address');
        }
    ]);
```

It throws me `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException` exception as the relation `address` is not defined for `admin`.
How do I solve this problem? I want fetch all the `posts` with `author` and include `address` in the authors that has an `address`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that by using the `whereHas` combine with `whereDoesntHave` to include both `Author` who has address and who doesn't have

```
$query = Post::with([
    'author' => function ($q) {
        $q->whereHas('address');
        $q->orWhereDoesntHave('address');
    }
]);
```

It you only `whereHas` without `orWhereDoesntHave` it will return only post which has `author` with existing `address` and not `author` which doesn't have `address` so to eager load both who has and who hasn't you include both `wherHas` and `orWhereDoesntHave`

- [whereDoesntHave](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/100ed71fe11a25908539c57368a048ec80c6123d/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php#L171)
- [whereHas](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/100ed71fe11a25908539c57368a048ec80c6123d/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php#L145)
- [orWhereDoesntHave](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/100ed71fe11a25908539c57368a048ec80c6123d/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.php#L183)

Comment: I throws error `Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::address does not exist.` I think because when it's trying to get `address` of `admin`, it can't. `orWhereDoesntHave()` still needs a valid relation.

Comment: have you already define a relation in your `Author` Model?

Comment: Yes there relations are already defined and I can query the relationship `address` when i'm only selecting the rows which `users` as Author. There's no `address` defined for `admins` as there isn't any

Comment: The error is throw when you try address `address` or when the query to fetch data from the database is executed?

Comment: The error throws when I call `$query->get()`